# combining jBPM in my spring-mvc application

Tags: spring-mvc, jbpm, bpmn

I would like to control the flow of an existing spring MVC web project using jBPM. 
 I think i want to make  .bpmn file that each task opens a jsp web page.
 Is it possible? How do you combine your existing project to be managed by jBPM?
 Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workitemHandler to represent a web page and use the engine to redirect your application from one page to the other. But that's not exactly a business process (the real reason why BPMN2 was designed, it not to automate a web application flow). so you need to analyze if doing that kind of automation will give you the flexibility that you are looking for.
Cheers